# Creating unique comboboxes in tabs of a notebook using tkinter and python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to create a program which will hold the sweep values of an RF directional coupler.

I have 5 couplers and each coupler has 4 forward ports.

I have managed to get the 5 couplers on seperate tabs of a tk notebook and loading the stored data from excel for a single port. the problem comes when i want to make the UI reload data for a different port using a combobox.

The code i have at the moment is:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    Notebook_Tabbed = ttk.Notebook(self)
    VHF_1, VHF_2 = ttk.Frame(Notebook_Tabbed), ttk.Frame(Notebook_Tabbed)
    Notebook_Tabbed.grid(column = 2, row = 2, columnspan = 5, sticky = "nwes")
    Notebook_Tabbed.add(VHF_1, text = ' VHF 1 '), Notebook_Tabbed.add(VHF_2, text = ' VHF 2 ')

    # Dictionaries to hold each couplers variables
    vhf_1_dict = {1 : [2, 7, 4, 5], 3 : [2, 7, 9, 10]}
    vhf_2_dict = {1 : [9, 14, 4, 5], 3 : [9, 14, 9, 10]}

    # Dictionary to hold above dictionaries
    var_dict = {VHF_1 : vhf_1_dict, VHF_2 : vhf_2_dict}

    def populate_table_tab(self, tab, Row_Start, Row_End, Column_Start,
                           Column_End, Coupler_Type, port):
        print(tab, Row_Start, Row_End, Column_Start,
                           Column_End, Coupler_Type, port)

    # Load data for chosen port
    def change_port(self, tab, port):
        populate_table_tab(self, tab, var_dict[tab][port][0], var_dict[tab][port][1], 
                          var_dict[tab][port][2], var_dict[tab][port][3], 'VHF', port)

    # Generate comboboxes for each tab of the notebook
    ports = StringVar()
    ports.set(1)

    def generate_port_selections(self, tab, row_num):
        port_selection = ttk.Combobox(tab, textvariable = ports, state = 'readonly',
                                      justify = "center")
        port_selection['values'] = (1, 3)
        port_selection.grid(column = 2, row = row_num, sticky = "nwes")
        port_selection.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', 
                             lambda _: change_port(self, tab, int(ports.get())))
        # _ denotes a throwaway argument required to make lambda work with a combobox event

    # Generate port selection comboboxes on each tab
    for tab, row_num in {VHF_1 : 4, VHF_2 : 11}.items():
        generate_port_selections(self, tab, row_num)
```

This code does work but it changes the combobox on all of the other tabs at the same time, without changing the data loaded from excel.

I have tried: `('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda i = i: change_port(self, tab, port_selection_list[i].get()))`   but   `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Event` occurs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also i posted this in a rush as i'm working and busy so if i have missed out any necessary code / information please ask.

Edit: Formatted code to be readable by making single lines into multiple.

Edit 2: Simplified code.

Edit 3: You should now be able to run the code within a blank container and frame from this code.

Comment: have you tried saving `port` as an attribute of the object? Perhaps its getting garbage collected.

Comment: @Bryan if adding self.port = port to change_port() is what you mean, then yes. It made no difference unfortunately. i also changed port to self.port in the method call within this method.

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since the problem seems to be with multiple pages, the MCVE will need to have no more than two, and probably no more than two values in the combobox, and no other widgets that aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: you have only one `StringVar` and you assing it to all `Comboboxes` so all `Comboboxes` display the same value from this `StringVar`. Every `Combobox` needs own  `StringVar`

Comment: @furas This isnt an issue when creating a `Label` or `Button` when using `lambda i=i:` but unfortunately it seems that I cannot use that with a `ComboBox`. I could always just create 5 different `ComboBoxes` with seperate code for each and a unique `StringVar` but i am trying to teach myself how to do it with a `for` loop so I can make it callable from other scripts which may want different numbers of `ComboBoxes`. If you know how to do this, then please post it and your help will be welcomed. `:)`

Comment: you have problem with `ports = StringVar()` (you create only one `StringVar`) - not with `lambda` - so `lambda i=i:` couldn't fix it and it could look like you can't use `lambda` with `Combobox`. But if you create 5 `StringVars` for 5 `Combobox` then you will see that you can use `lambda` with `Combobox`.

Comment: you have to use `ports = StringVar()` inside `generate_port_selections()` to create new unique `ports` for new `Combobox`.

Comment: @furas Well blow me sideways. I actually thought I had tried that.... Obviously not as it worked. Thank you for your help!! If you create an answer I can mark it as accepted. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem because you create only one `StringVar` (`ports = StringVar()`) and you use it with all `Combobox( textvariable=ports )` so they share the same information.

You have to use `ports = StringVar()` inside `generate_port_selections()` to create new unique `ports` for new `Combobox`.